# Remove a field from C# form after post back?

Tags: c#, forms, collections, request, postback

How can we remove a field from the Request.Form Collection

```
 Request.Form.Remove("myfield");
```

**Gives error : Collection is read-only.**

**EDIT:** I am sending a form to an External API and it don't require a field and gives a error. and that field is required by me in my internal application .To send the form I use

```
XXX_API.Post(Request.Form, ID);
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you ultimately want to achieve as the end result? Manipulating forms in this manner isn't really done, but you could remove/disable the control, perhaps, depends.

Comment: @GrantThomas : See note in my edit

Comment: Request.Form is untouchable. Wrap it in another collection, leaving out what you don't need.

Comment: @Alex: I am new to c# can you please suggest or show me some code to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HttpRequest.Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form.aspx) is just a [NameValueCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx). You are free to create another NameValueCollection based on the data in the form that you need to provide to the API, leaving out whatever fields you can't post to the API. You can then send your new NameValueCollection to the API.

If you want to pick and choose the keys, you can use the following:

```
NameValueCollection formToPost = new NameValueCollection();

formToPost.Add("SomeKey", Request.Form["SomeKey"]);
formToPost.Add("AnotherKey", Request.Form["AnotherKey"]);

XXX_API.Post(formToPost, ID);
```

Alternatively, if you want everything, but the one key, you can use the following, which is a bit more simple. It makes use of an [overloaded constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s711zk3.aspx), and the [Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.remove.aspx) method.

```
NameValueCollection formToPost = new NameValueCollection(Request.Form);    
formToPost.Remove("FieldToRemove");

XXX_API.Post(formToPost, ID);
```